# Creating a PsiElement from an ASTNode with implied nodes and out of order children

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, abstract-syntax-tree, intellij-plugin

Is it OK for a custom language plugin using IntelliJ's plugin SDK to produce a *PSIElement* tree where

- some *PSIElement*s have no associated *ASTNode*, so where `myPsiElement.getNode() == null`
- some *PSIElement*s have children out of order, e.g. `myPsiElement.children()[0].getStartOffsetInParent() > myPsiElement.children()[1].getStartOffsetInParent()`
- some *PSIElement*s correspond to zero characters in the source: `myPsiElement.getTextLength() == 0`

Would any of these properties make it harder to take advantage of language plugin SDK features?

---

For background:

I'm creating a custom language plugin for IntelliJ per "[Implementing a Parser and PSI](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/implementing_parser_and_psi.html)."

The bottom of the diagram from the docs shows the relationship between *ASTNode*s and *PsiElement*s.

IIUC, first, a lexer segments the text into tokens.  Then a parser drops node start and end marks between tokens to specify the parse tree structure.  Intellij internals lift that token stream with markers into a (not-very abstract) *ASTNode* tree.  Finally, language-specific plugin code builds a PSI tree from the AST.

[image]

It looks like, from that diagram, that every node in the Psi tree is associated with an *ASTElement*.

This relationship seems bidirectional per [`PsiElement.getNode()`](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-40e5005d02df57f58ac2d498867446c43d61101f/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement.java?nav=22087:22105:focused&line=589&preview=false).  The diagram doesn't show an arrow between *MyPsiFile* and the *MyElementType.FILE* *ASTNode* but
 [`PsiFile.getNode()`](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-40e5005d02df57f58ac2d498867446c43d61101f/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiFile.java?nav=2848:2871:focused&line=113&preview=false) suggests there has to be one.

For language-specific reasons, my existing parser produces a tree that don't clearly fit this model.

- Nodes can appear out of order.
  The expression `a + b` parses to a node like `(call + a b)`.  Note that infix and postfix operators are shifted left to before their first operand.
- The parser synthesizes some nodes that correspond to no tokens, and so the relationship between them and an AST node is unclear.  For example I need to produce distinct trees for

  - `for (x;;) body`
  - `for (;x;) body`
  - `for (;;x) body`

  so the parser inserts symbols like the `init=` in `(for init= x body)` which the definition of *for* can use to decide what to do with `x`.

There is a concept of a ["non-physical" *PSIElement*](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/680b2141055c30c94bdf2dfc2b2282bf767325f6/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiElement.java#L544):

> ```
> /**
>  * Checks if an actual source or class file corresponds to the element. Non-physical elements include,
>  * for example, PSI elements created for the watch expressions in the debugger.
>  * Non-physical elements do not generate tree change events.
>  * Also, {@link PsiDocumentManager#getDocument(PsiFile)} returns null for non-physical elements.
> ```

but it's unclear to me if those are associated with *ASTNode*s or if that's right for nodes that are implied by program text.

Comment: I'd like to understand your statements about your language-specific departure from the element/node relationship. I would have thought that this is the difference between the parse tree and the AST. Your parse tree for a prefix notation language would differ from an infix variant, but the AST would be the same, no? 

Also have you found your answer?

Comment: @ChrisMountford, I haven't found a good answer.  Yes.  My parse tree for `a + b` is `[InfixPlus, [Leaf, "a"], "+", [Leaf, "b"]]` while the AST is `(+ a b)`.  In the diagram above which shows Intellij's parser pipeline, there is no parse tree→AST step; one goes from a stream of tokens to a stream of tokens with embedded parentheses straight to an "AST."

Comment: RIght now, I create an Intellij AST that wraps my parse tree, and use position metadata to map my parse tree nodes to my AST nodes.  This lets my plugin code find my AST corresponding to an Intellij AST node.